# Improve my if-statement to prevent double checks

Tags: java

I write the following version of an if-statement very often. And every time, I hate the way that I make it, but I don't know how to improve it.

For example, I have two `ArrayList`'s. If one of them is not empty, then I convert it to a `StringBuilder` and send it per mail. The problem is, first I check if one of them is not empty to know if I should send a mail, and then I check it again to know which of them is not empty. Example code:

```
if(!array1.isEmpty() || !array2.isEmpty()){
   // I need to distinguish the StringBuilder
   StringBuilder array1string = new StringBuilder();
   StringBuilder array2string = new StringBuilder();
   // so one of them is not empty. but which? now I must double check it
   if(!array1.isEmpty()){
      for(String string : array1){
         array1string.append(string);
      }
   }
   if(!array2.isEmpty()){
      for(String string : array2){
         array2string.append(string);
      }
   }
   mail.sendMail("Array1: " + array1string == null?"-":array1string.toString() 
      + ", Array2: " + array2string == null?"-":array2string.toString());
}
```

So is there a way to prevent this double check?

Comment: `array1string` and `array2string` will never be equal to `null`; you're giving them each a value near the start of the code segment. They might result in empty strings, but they're not `null`.

Comment: @dTDesign: Do you know that the mail that is sent might still indicate that both arrays are empty?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your code can be shortened to:

```
if(!array1.isEmpty() || !array2.isEmpty()) {
    mail.sendMail("Array1: " + getContent(array1) + ", Array2: " + getContent(array2));
}
```

When you have:

```
String getContent(ArrayList<String> list) {
    if(!list.isEmpty()) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(String string : list) {
            sb.append(string);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
    return "-";
}
```

Comment: You mean `if (!array.isEmpty())`

Comment: This is why I love this site. very elegant way. Thanks!

Comment: I think the whole code block inside `getArrayContent` method can be substituted with `return array.isEmpty() ? "-" : Arrays.toString(array);`

Comment: @tintinmj `Arrays.toString()` adds `,`, `[` and `]` to the output, something that OP does not want.

Comment: The OP said they were `ArrayLists`, not *arrays*. `String[]` should be `List<String>`, and the method can actually be built with generics to support any kind of list. I'll add an answer to show how.

Answer (score 11):

Adam's answer is good, but I just couldn't resist modifying his method a bit:

```
<E> String getArrayContent(Collection<E> list) {
    if(list.isEmpty())
        return "-";

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(E value : list) {
        sb.append(value);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

This method has the following modifications compared to Adam's:

- It uses `Collection` because you stated that you were using `ArrayList` in the question. (And this method works with any type of collection, not only `List` or `ArrayList`). `Collection` is the superinterface which declares both `isEmpty()` and extends `Iterable`
- It uses generics so it can be used for any kind of collection, not only `Collection<String>`
- I prefer to return early to simplify readability and not have to indent code more than necessary

If you also want a method for regular arrays, that method could call the method for collections by converting the array to a list:

```
<E> String getArrayContent(E[] array) {
    return getArrayContent(Arrays.asList(array));
}
```